# Is density of an element directly proportional to atomic number or atomic weight?

Tags: mass, atomic-physics, density

Is the density of an element directly proportional to any power/order of atomic weight or atomic number? I know very less, probably only highschool level physics, after which my brain has been bothered less about physics and more about computers. Can anyone help me with this highschool level question?